# PyQt5 QLineEdit loop-- image added

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to make a P2P chat application.

So I have this sig / slot pieces together myself. What I need to achieve is that I want to enter text in the `QLineEdit` (named it `send_box`) and display in the `QTextedit` (named it `main_text`).

[image]

```
self.send_box.returnPressed.connect(self.sendData)
```

and here is the function definition

```
  def sendData(self):
        self.main_text.setText ('Hello World')
```

This works. But only send the `"Hello World"` to the `QTextEdit` when I press Enter key.

What I need is to send the text from the `send_box` (`QLineEdit`).

Comment: do you need `self.send_box.getText()` or something similar ?

Comment: To make it easy it's like this:

1) I have a QTextEdit --Named it main_text
2) I have a QLineEdit --Named it send_box

so the data i Enter in (send_box) i want it to display in (main_text). 

self.main_text.setText = self.send_box()

Comment: `self.main_text.setText( self.send_box.getText() )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get text from `send_box` and

- replace text in `main_text`

  ```
  self.main_text.setText( self.send_box.text() )
  ```
- append to existing text in `main_text`

  ```
  self.main_text.append( self.send_box.text() )
  ```

And then you can clear text in `send_box`

```
self.send_box.clear()
```

See doc for `Qt5` (it's similar for `PyQt5`): [QTextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) and [QLineEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html)

Full example

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

        self.vbox.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(text='Input:'))
        self.linetext = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.linetext)

        self.linetext.returnPressed.connect(self.on_press_enter)

        self.vbox.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(text='Output:'))
        self.textedit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.textedit)

        self.show()

    def on_press_enter(self):
        # copy from LineText to TextEdit
        #self.textedit.setText(self.linetext.text())
        self.textedit.append(self.linetext.text())
        # clear LineText
        self.linetext.clear()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MyWindow()
app.exec()
```